# What's different between "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN" and "250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN"?

Tags: email, smtp

I can see many ehlo command echo from mail server like this:

[image]

I want to know what's different between "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN" and "250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN"? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### They mean the same thing, but one is for backwards compatibility.

The first one, `250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN`, is the modern RFC-compliant way for a mail server to announce what authentication methods it supports. Authenticated SMTP is used to allow valid remote users to send mail through an SMTP server while still preventing spammers from connecting and using it as a relay.

The second example, `250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN`, is an identical command but is intended for non-RFC-compliant email clients. Older clients, such as Outlook 2003 and older, did not implement the `AUTH` command correctly and instead expected an equals sign between `AUTH` and the available authentication methods.

For backwards compatibility, it is possible to enable both the compliant and non-compliant `AUTH` commands. In Postfix, for example, you can enable the [broken_sasl_auth_clients](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#broken_sasl_auth_clients) option to force Postfix to broadcast `AUTH` twice. Otherwise, only the RFC-compliant `AUTH` command should be used.

Answer (score 0):

they mean the same thing, the first one is the proper one but some mail clients only recognize the second line